# using preg_replace() with wordpress filter the_content

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to append a php query to the end of links from my website to a sponsor site using `the_content` filter and `preg_replace()`.  I have tested my regex expression on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) and it works. I have also used `print_r()` to test that the function is being called but for some reason the links are not being changed in practice. Here is the code I am having trouble with

```
add_filter('the_content', 'linkAppend');

function linkAppend($content) {
  global $referalString;

  preg_replace('/\/\/(www|launch)?\.?(solarwinds\.com)\/[^"]*/g','$&?cmp='.$referalString, $content);
  return $content;
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, or let me know where I went wrong, I would be greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had multiple problems, it was pointed out to me that I wasn't assigning the output of my `preg_replace( )` to `$content` and then I found and solved issues with the global flag on the regular expression not being valid in php and me not accounting for links without a `/` after the `.com`.  Final fix looks like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'linkAppend');

function linkAppend($content) {
  global $referalString;
  $content = preg_replace('/\/\/(www|launch)?\.?(solarwinds\.com)\/?[^"]*/m','$0?cmp='.$referalString, $content);
  return $content;
}
```